# Does downloading with multiple threads actually speed things up?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, download

So, I was starting up minecraft a few days ago and opened up it's developer console to see what it was doing while it was updating itself. I noticed one of the lines said the following:

```
Downloading 32 files. (16 threads)
```

Now, the first thing that came to mind was: the processor can still only do one thing at a time, all threads do is split each of their tasks up and distribute the CPU power between them, so what would the purpose be of downloading multiple files on multiple threads if each thread is still only being run on a single processor?

Then, in the process of deciding whether or not I should ask this question on SO, I remembered that multiple cores can reside on one processor. For example, my processor is quad-core. So, you can actually accomplish 4 downloads truly simultaneously. Now that sounds like it makes sense. Except for the fact that there are 16 threads being use for minecraft's download. So, basically my question is:

Does increasing the number of threads during a download help the speed at all? (Assuming a multi-core processor, and the thread count is less than the core count.)

And

If you increase the number of threads to past the number of cores, does speed still increase? (It sounds to me like the downloads would be max-speed after 4 threads, on a quad-core processor.)

Comment: Probably not. Unless you have multiple internet connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downloads are network-bound, not CPU-bound. So theoretically, using multiple threads will not make it faster.

On the one hand, if your program downloads using synchronous (blocking) I/O, then multiple threads simply enables less blocking to occur. In general, on the other hand, it is more sensible to just use a single thread with asynchronous I/O.

On the gripping hand, asynchronous I/O is trickier to code correctly than synchronous I/O (which is straightforward). So the developers may have just decided to favour ease of programming over pure performance. (Or they may favour compatibility with older Java platforms: real async I/O is only available with NIO2 (which came with Java 7).)

Comment: Interesting, could you explain the difference between synchronous and asynchronous IO?

Comment: @AndrewG Here's the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) on it. If you'd like me to explain something there, I can try.

Comment: On the griping hand... eeew are the moties lose this time? :)

Answer (score 4):

When one thread downloads one file, it will spend some time waiting.  When one thread downloads N files, one after another, it will spend, on average, N times as much total wait time.

When N threads each download one file, each of those threads will spend some time waiting, but some of those waits will be overlapped (e.g., thread A and thread B are both waiting at the same time.)  The end result is that it *may* take less wall-clock time to get all N of the files.

On the other hand, if the threads are waiting for files from the same server, each thread's individual wait time may be longer.

The question of whether or not there is an over-all performance benefit depends on the client, on the server, and on the available network bandwidth.  If the network can't carry bytes as fast as the server can pump them out, then multi-threading the client probably won't save any time, if the server is single-threaded, then multi-threading the client definitely won't help, but if the conditions are right (e.g., if you have a fast internet connection and especially if the files are coming from a server *farm* instead of a single machine), then multi-threading potentially can speed things up.

Comment: This still assumes a synchronous I/O model. As my answer points out, there are ways to download multiple files simultaneously using only a single thread.

Comment: Re "synchronous I/O," That's true, there are other ways besides the use of synchronous calls from multiple threads to overlap I/O, but the _question_ specifically was about using threads. That's why my answer only talks about threads.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it will not be faster, but there are always exceptions.

Assuming for each download thread, you are opening a new connection, then if

1. The network (either your own network, or target system) is limiting the download speed for each connection, or
2. You are downloading from multiple servers, and etc

Or, if the "download" is not a plain download, but downloading something and do some CPU intensive processing on that.

In such cases you may see download speed become faster when having multiple thread.